# Angular: ng-repeat orderBy filter

Tags: angularjs

Given the following, I want to order this list by `displayOrder`

```
angular.module('app').value('sidebarMenus', {
    'Sites': {
        displayName: 'Sites',
        displayOrder: 0
    },
    'Inspections': {
        displayName: 'Inspections',
        displayOrder: 1,
        items: [
            { name: 'Create New', state: 'Admin.UserList' }
        ]
    },
    'Permits': {
        displayName: 'Permits',
        displayOrder: 2
    },
    'Compliance': {
        displayName: 'Compliance',
        displayOrder: 3
    },
    'Accounts': {
        displayName: 'Accounts',
        displayOrder: 4
    },
    'Documents': {
        displayName: 'Documents',
        displayOrder: 5
    },
    'Queries': {
        displayName: 'Queries',
        displayOrder: 6
    },
    'Reports': {
        displayName: 'Reports',
        displayOrder: 7
    },
    'Admin': {
        displayName: 'Admin',
        displayOrder: 8,
        items: [
            { name: 'Users', state: 'Admin.UserList' },
            { name: 'Groups', state: 'Admin.GroupList' },
            { name: 'Workgroups', state: 'na' },
        ]
    }
});
```

I have this, but it does not work. For some reason this is sorted alphabetically by default.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in sidebar.menus | orderBy: item.displayOrder">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-ng-bind="item.displayName" data-ng-click="sidebar.menu.setMenu(item)"></a>
</li>
```

**Result**

```
Accounts
Admin
Compliance
Documents
Inspections
Permits
Queries
Reports
Sites
```

Comment: In the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04), the `orderBy` is based on a property on the model itself, which stores the name of the property you want to order by. Add a property `orderProp = "displayOrder"`, then use it in the `repeat`: `orderBy: orderProp`.

Comment: @danradu - That did not work, still sorts alphabetically.

Comment: Did you try just `data-ng-repeat="item in sidebar.menus | orderBy: 'displayOrder'`? for me using the example in the tutorial worked with no problem. What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sidebarMenus` is an object. `orderBy` can only be applied to arrays. You can't sort the properties of an object ;)